# how can I find span element with no id and class defined by using .not() jQuery build-in function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three div element, one of them has span element inside with no id and class defined. I was wondering that If I can use .not() function to set the background of other two div element.

```js
$(function() {

  $("div").not($("span")).css("background-color", "yellow");


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3
  <span>div中的span</span>
</div>
```

I have tried the approach above, but all three div elements are colored.

Comment: A div is inheriently never going to be a span.  The `not()` evaluates against what you are.  Not what you contain.

Comment: This should work:  $("div:not(:has(span))").css("background-color", "yellow");

Comment: @gaetanoM i was about to post this as an answser, but saw your comment .You should post it, it's the answer the op looked for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in order to select all the divs with no span inside:

```
 $("div:not(:has(span))").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

The snippet:

```js
$("div:not(:has(span))").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3
  <span>div中的span</span>
</div>
```